# Like how you can do multiple 'sed' commands (delimited by ';') can you do this with 'awk -F'? It works with multiple 'awk' but not with 'awk-F'

Tags: text-processing, awk

you can call sed multiple times without using multiple pipes by delimiting the cmds with `;` (thanks guys…) is there a way to use this for multiple `awk -F` cmds?

#### Using `sed` multiple pipes

```bash
echo "'text';" | \
sed s"#';##"g  | \ 
sed s"#'##"g   

text
```

#### Using `sed` with `;` as delimter

```bash
echo "'text';" | \
sed "            \
  s#';##g;       \
  s#'##g         \
"

text
```

#### Edit:

So you can join multiple `awk` cmds using `;`. But can't do so for multiple `awk -F` cmds

The question is about stringing multiple  `awk -F` cmds which is still unanswered.

#### Background

```bash
# '/x/ gives the href of the actual videos
# awk -F '/x/' '{print$2}’ 
# because the /x/ is unique to the video urls
# after this the video links appear
# but I have to get rid of stuff 
# on the right of them so I do 
# awk —F 'title' '{print$1}' 
# this returns all the video links 
# but they have a double quotes 
# and a semi colon on the end.

curl -s                                 \
  https://site.com/plist/page={0..50} | \
grep '/x/'                            | \
awk -F '/x/' '{print$2}'              | \
awk -F 'title' '{print$1}'            | \
sed '                                   \
  s#";##g;                              \
  s#"##g                                \
'
```

So now I have a bunch of video links and do further processing to get the video download links, I then use `mapfile` to get the download links into an array and use `parallel` to download them.

I shortened a lot of the stuff I actually do in that code example.

#### Edit:

So it can’t be done. Thanks a lot to that user.

This user commented about using `sed` for one of my specific cases which would remove the need for `awk -F` but I have at least 20 other cases. But it gives me something to think about, the reasons i was doing, `awk -F` is it because it got me the stuff I needed without knowing any sed regex.

Anyway thanks all I wanted to know if it could be done and it can’t so I’m satisfied.

#### Thanks

To @StèphaneChazelas, their comment solved my problem.

Comment: If you're using multiple pipes to call sed and/or grep and/or awk multiple times than you almost certainly have the wrong approach.

Comment: You don't need the `-e` option in `sed` to do what you describe.  You can achieve the same effect simply by joining the various expressions with semicolons or newlines into a single one.

Comment: This isn’t about `sed -e` but thanks, this is about an equivalent, `awk` version that joins the expressions the same as you would with `sed` delimited by semi colons

Comment: I wanted `-F`  go set field seperators…

Comment: I can't imagine what `-F` has to do with an awk equivalent of `sed -e`. You can set `FS` wherever you like, as often as you like, in an awk script. Ask a new, clear question if you'd like help as this one has become extremely muddy and confusing. Make sure to ask about WHAT you want to do, not HOW to implement what you think you should do as I think that was the root of the issue with this question, it's an XY question and we couldn't figure out what the real problem is you're trying to solve.

Comment: the question asked was along the lines of 'like how you can string multiple sed commands using sed -e, is there a way to do this with awk -F'. But ok I'll ask a new question, because  although you can join multiple `awk` cmds delimited by a `;` you can't join multiple `awk -F` cmds delimited by a `;` now from what that other user said it seems I can get the functionality of setting the field separator multiple times using 1 `awk` cmd if I do it with `FS` I suggest you read her comment in her answer, to see if this is even a viable question to ask and get back to me please, by @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: I think you're confused about what `awk -F` does - it just sets `FS` before the script runs. If you need to change `FS` while your script is running you can do that, but you can't use `-F` to do it as `-F` is an **argument** to awk that's parsed before the script starts.

Comment: Regarding `So it can’t be done. Thanks a lot to that user.` - that all depends what `it` (i.e. the problem you're trying to solve)is, which we don't know yet, but I'm sure it can easily be done, whatever it is. Regarding `Thanks To @StèphaneChazelas, her comment solved my problem.` - I'm pretty sure Stèphane is male (https://www.smh.com.au/technology/stephane-chazelas-the-man-who-found-the-webs-most-dangerous-internet-security-bug-20140926-10mixr.html) and if you mean their answer then the way to identify that would be to [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: it wouldn't be fair on the user who answered that you can't delimit `awk -F` like you can with `awk` although I wanted to give the vote to give him... Which is why I asked that other question so I could give him credit.

Comment: I really hope you do ask a new question about whatever it is you want to do as I think several of us are very curious about what that is and would be happy to answer it for you. So far you have a lot of answers to a lot of different questions, (some right, some wrong, some efficient/robust/portable, others not so much, etc.) but I don't know if any of them are the best answer to what I THINK you really want to do and certainly none of them are ONLY the best solution for you so idk how you'll be able to pick that out. All the best either way.

Comment: I don't think I will able to unfortunately, my question was how to join 1 `awk -F` with multiple other `-F` cmds like you can do with `awk` (delimited by a `;`) I really don't know what's ambiguous about that. It's been answered that you can't do that with `awk -F` @StéphaneChazelas has given me a way to set `FS` multiple times in 1 `awk` cmd which is what I wanted, he just used different syntax. Anyway I'll have more questions and hope to see you again.

Comment: To be clear, setting FS multiple times is [almost?] never the right approach to solving any problem given a single input file (e.g. see Stéphane solution using `split()` instead for a better approach) so if that's your takeaway and is what you're now doing in your code, you should really ask a new question. Anyway, glad you found a way to make progress with your script, you can always ask followup questions some other time.

Comment: it's just that it was so easy and quick to do the processing I was doing, a monkey could probably do it. I'll have a look at `split()`, this was just a personal 'project' and I love to learn new ways, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to answer your question, no I don't believe you can do multiple `-F` bits, since you're just updating the `FS` variable, but it only gets applied once for the line being read. (i.e. value of `$1` won't change based on changing `FS`).

That said, you're only trying to pull out the url from some lines, maybe looking something like these, right?

```
.../x/URL1";title...  
.../x/URL2";title...  
.../x/URL3";title...
```

etc. for lines with `/x/` in them. So you can match the front and ends of the line that you don't want ( `.../x/` and `";title...` ) and say just keep the rest, no?

So tell `sed` you just want the bit that doesn't match - everything between `\(` and `\)` will be called `\1`. In other words:

```bash
sed 's#.*/x/\(.*\)";title.*#\1#'
```

and with your example:

```bash
curl -s                                 \
  https://site.com/plist/page={0..50} | \
  grep '/x/'                          | \
  sed 's#.*/x/\(.*\)";title.*#\1#'
```

Comment: thank you, you’re the first to answer the question. I use `awk -F` as it gets me what with low effort and it’s quick and easy (I don’t have to really know anything)  I’m not that familiar with regex.

Comment: You never need to pipe grep to sed and that sed command can fail given various URLS. Regarding `value of $1 won't change based on changing FS` - yes, it will if you do it right but we're still waiting to hear from the OP what they actually need to do.

Answer (score 11):

**Update:** The question was [altered substantially](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/714915/2) after this answer was posted, so the original answer - while still true - does not help much in solving the *actual* problem of the OP.

It would seem that you try to process `curl` output of the form

```
Ignore this
http://some.url.involving/x/'video-link-1';title...
http://some.url.involving/x/'video-link-2';title...
Ignore that
```

etc., where you want to

1. only process lines where `/x/` appears, and
2. extract the part in between `' ... '`

The easiest way is to simply use one field separator, the `'`:

```bash
curl -s https://site.com/plist/page={0..50} | awk -F"'" '/\/x\//{print $2}'
```

This will in addition only consider lines that contain the `/x/` pattern. So, for the above example, the output would be

```
video-link-1
video-link-2
```

**If you want to do it by splitting at changing field separators**, you can of course change the internal `FS` variable mid-way as indicated in the [answer by Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/714975/377345). However, in that case I would rather use the fact that a multi-character field separator, whether set via `-F` as option parameter or via assignment of `FS` inside the `awk` program, is treated as a full regular expression.

That means you can use an "or"-type alternative as field separator to cover both cases in one (but you should then also include the single quote and semicolon to avoid further post-processing needs):

```bash
curl -s https://site.com/plist/page={0..50} |
   awk -F'/x/\047|\047;title' '/\/x\//{print $2}'
```

- This will set the field separator to be *either* `/x/'` *or* `';title`.
- It will only consider lines that contain the `/x/` pattern. On these lines, it will print the second field, which is the information you wanted (and already stripped of the `'` and `;`).
- The single quotes are expressed as ASCII code `\047` to avoid having the "single quote inside single quotes" problem (I will just assume your operating system is an ASCII-based system, not [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)).

---

**Another approach often encountered** is to "replace the entire line by only the interesting part", as in

```bash
curl -s https://site.com/plist/page={0..50} |
   awk '/\/x\//{print gensub(/.*\/x\/\047([^\047]+).*/,"\\1","1")}'
```

This will again only consider lines where the pattern `/x/` appears, replace the entire line by the content between single-quotes that follow this pattern, and print the modified line to extract only that part.

The same is possible with a single `sed` call, albeit representation of a single-quote via ASCII code doesn't work here, so it is a little more involved. Assuming GNU `sed` with the `-E` option for ERE:

```bash
curl -s https://site.com/plist/page={0..50} | sed -n -E 's|.*\/x\/'\''([^'\'']+).*|\1|p'
```

This will suppress output by default `-n`, perform the substitution just like in the `awk` case, and print (the trailing `p`) *only if a substitution was made*, which implies that the `/x/'video-link';title` pattern was found.

---

**Original answer below**

**Frame challenge:** Is it necessary?

In `awk`, you can repeat any modifying commands within the same program as often as you want, as in

```
echo "'text';" | awk '{gsub(/\047;/,""); gsub(/\047/,"")} 1'
```

or

```
echo "'text';" | awk '{gsub(/\047;/,"")} {gsub(/\047/,"")} 1'
```

(using `\047` to express single-quotes inside the single-quoted program).

And you can also write it up in an easy-to-read way, say

```
echo "'text';" |
  awk '{gsub(/\047;/,"")};
       {gsub(/\047/,"")}; 1'
```

or as a dedicated program:

```
echo "'text';" | awk -f multi-substitute.awk
```

with `multi-substitute.awk` looking like

```c
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{gsub(/\047;/,"")}
{gsub(/\047/,"")}
1
```

Comment: the problem is your solutions have complicated esoteric regexes, whereas me using `sed` or `awk` is much more readable, simple and requires no specialist knowledge.

Comment: Nickotine I'm sorry if it feels like I'm picking on you, I'm honestly just trying to help you get a good answer to this question and any future questions you ask. This answer has the most upvotes for your question (so it's the best answer as far as the community can tell) and @AdminBee obviously put some effort into trying to help you. Downvoting such a good answer because you don't have a decent understanding of regular expressions (and accepting a poor answer with a more complicated regexp!) is kinda outrageous and likely to dissuade people from trying to help you further.

Comment: @Nickotine I am curious at what point simply setting the field separator to the character enclosing your desired sub-string, and printing exactly that field, requires "specialist knowledge". But well ...

Comment: err well you got me there... I'll give you your upvote back simply for that reply :)

Comment: ahh damn I can't do it :(

Comment: specialist knowledge meaning your crazy regexes you use for `sed` and that crazy thing you do with `awk` just to remove single quotes and a semi colon

Comment: @EdMorton look at the way he uses `sed` and `awk` to remove single quotes and a semi colon, then compare it to my sed example. Which requires much less effort and is more readable?

Comment: @Nickotine Ah well - no problem, no hard feelings. But keep in mind, that is a "single-line" `awk` program that replaces your whole chain of piping - something that in most cases is much more inefficient and can fail in unexpected (and at first sight unexplainable) ways - so the program does more than simply remove single quotes and a semicolon, it extracts the string you are interested in from the whole line.

Comment: apologies clearly you know much more than me, I'll keep all you said in mind and start learning regexes...

Answer (score 8):

What's wrong with:

```bash
echo "'text';" | sed "
  s/';//g
  s/'//g
"
```

Or:

```bash
awk -v q="'" '
  {
    gsub(q ";", "")
    gsub(q, "")
    print
  }'
```

Or:

```bash
awk -v q="'" '
  {
    gsub(q ";", "")
  }
  {
    gsub(q, "")
  }
  {
    print
  }'
```

for that matter?

No need for several `-e`s. Except maybe for (t)csh where it's a PITA, most shells are perfectly fine with you entering multiline arguments.

`-e arg` in `sed` is actually specified as adding newline followed by `arg` to the `sed` code, so

```bash
sed -e foo -e bar
```

is meant to be the exact same as

```bash
sed 'foo
bar'
```

Nothing stopping you also doing:

```bash
NL='
' # or NL=$'\n' with most modern shells.

sed_cmd1='s/foo/bar' awk_cmd1='gsub(/foo/, "bar")'
sed_cmd2='s/bar/baz' awk_cmd2='gsub(/bar/, "baz")'

sed "$sed_cmd1$NL$sed_cmd2"
# or
awk "{$awk_cmd1$NL$awk_cmd2${NL}print}"
```

Or:

```bash
awk "$(printf '%s\n' '{gsub("foo", "bar"}' '{gsub("bar", "baz")}')"
```

In `awk` syntax, you can replace newline to delimit commands with with `;`. In `sed` as well but only after a limited number of commands (not after `w`, `r`, `:`, `a`, `c`, `i`, `b`, `t`, `}`, `#` or the `s` command if the `w` flag is used for instance, at least portably).

To avoid having to worry about quoting, you can also do:

```bash
awk "$(<<'EOF' cat
  {
    gsub("';", "") # ' " \ not a problem
    gsub("'", "")
    print
  }
EOF
)"
```

Or on most systems:

```bash
awk -f /dev/fd/3 3<<'EOF'
  {
    gsub("';", "") # ' " \ not a problem
    gsub("'", "")
    print
  }
EOF
```

(note the quotes around the first `EOF` to make sure no expansion is performed by the shell in the here-document)

---

As to your edit about multiple `-F`s (not to be confused with `-f`):

`-F x` is to set the field separator to `x`, it's the same as `-v FS=x` or adding a `BEGIN { FS = "x" }`.

Doing `-F ' ' -F '|' -F ','` won't help you getting the 1st `,`-delimited field of the 3rd `|`-delimited field of the 2nd whitespace delimited field in `foo a|b|x,y,z|c bar` for instance. That would just set `FS` to `,`.

For that you'd need:

```
awk '
  {
    split($0, a, " ")
    split(a[2], b, "|")
    split(b[3], c, ",")
    print c[1]
  }'
```

Or using `FS`:

```
awk '
  {
    FS = " "; $0 = $2
    FS = "|"; $0 = $3
    FS = ","; print $1
  }'
```

Where `FS` is used here to split `$0` (the contents of the current record initially) when `$x` (with x >= 1) is accessed.

IOW, to be able to reduce

```
awk '{print "something out of "$0}' |
  awk '{print "something out of "$0" as modified by the first}'
```

You'd need:

```
awk '
  {
    $0 = "something out of "$0
    print "something out of "$0" as modified by the first
  }'
```

You can easily reduce two `sed`s doing one `s/x/y/` each or the equivalent with two `awk`s doing `{gsub("x", "y"); print}`, but you can't necessarily apply the same recipe for any `sed` or `awk` code, you just need to understand how they work and that they work on one record at a time as the streams of text comes in.

Comment: so if I use the `FS` version would it work for something like this: ```echo 'https://ex.com/code' | awk —F '://' '{print$2}' | awk —F 'ex.com/' '{print$2}' ``` and that should leave 'code' excuse the example, but if you can do that with `FS` can you show me how?

Comment: I’m assuming with your version I won’t need pipes which is shat I want

Comment: eagerly waiting on your reply

Answer (score 5):

### `sed` and `-e`

> ```
> echo "'text';" | sed s"#';##"g  | sed s"#'##"g  
> text
>
> echo "'text';" | sed -e s"#';##"g -e s"#'##"g  
> text
> ```

It usually isn't necessary to use multiple commands and usually isn't necessary to use `-e` twice (just use a semi-colon).  It is probably faster to allow one single instance of awk or sed to process both operations.

```bash
$ echo "'text';" | sed "s/';//g; s/'//g"
text
```

I might have done this using capturing

```bash
$ echo "'text';" | sed -r "s/'([^']*)';/\1/g"
text
```

Of course I don't doubt your simple example was a placeholder for a pair of programs that can't be easily combined in this way. However I wouldn't like newbies to get the wrong impression. Simple operations are best combined in this way.

---

### `awk` and `-F`

> ```
> curl -s                                 \
>   https://site.com/plist/page={0..50} | \
> grep '/x/'                            | \
> awk -F '/x/' '{print$2}'              | \
> awk -F 'title' '{print$1}'            | \
> sed '                                   \
>   s#";##g;                              \
>   s#"##g                                \
> '
> ```

For AWK, as others have pointed out, rather than trying to set different field separators for different expressions, it is probably better to use a different approach entirely. If a regular expression can adequately express the structure of all the data to be encountered, that may be the best way to extract an item from a string with mixed delimiters. Regular expressions are often overused but they should not be overlooked.

Given this data:

```bash
$ cat /tmp/titles.txt
preamble
p/q/r/s/title"Not This";Brick
something
a/x/b/c/title"The Rime of the Ancient Mariner";Coleridge
otherthing
f/g/x/h/title"Jackass";Knoxville
remainder
```

I'd probably try to do the whole of the above task in Perl

```bash
$ curl -s file:///tmp/titles.txt | \
> perl -n -e 'print "$1\n" if m{/x/.*title"([^"]*)";}'
The Rime of the Ancient Mariner
Jackass
```

It can probably be done as easily using Curl and a single AWK program. I'm no expert on AWK but I might start with the following and refine it

```bash
$ curl -s file:///tmp/titles.txt | \
> awk '/\/x\// {gsub(".*title\"",""); gsub("\";.*",""); print}'
The Rime of the Ancient Mariner
Jackass
```

---

(Gnu Sed 4.2.2, Perl 5.18.2. Gnu AWK 4.0.1)

Comment: I didn’t know you could do that, thanks a lot. Now I just have to solve my problem with awk, I’m going to update the question m, have a look.

Comment: I feel like you moved the goalposts a lot. Nevertheless this answer might still be useful for other people whose search results include your question.  Andre Beaud has written the answer I would have written to your revised/clarified question. (except you could everything in one AWK invocation)

Comment: i just removed `sed -e` and used `sed` with the delimter so people would stop going on about that and actually answer the question

Comment: Really? You believe that `'cmd₁; cmd₂'` is *faster* than `-e cmd₁ -e cmd₂`? The man page says `-e` means ‘Add *this* command to the end of the script of editing commands.’

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' The original form of the question used multiple commands as well as multiple -e options and I conflated the points that both were unecessary and the first inefficient (without any compensating improvement in clarity etc). I have revised the answer to present those points more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a fancy GNU `awk` then yes

```
% printf abc'\n' | gawk -e '{print}' -e '{print}'
abc
abc
```

otherwise, probably, no.

```
% printf abc'\n' | awk -e '{print}' -e '{print}'
awk: unknown option -e ignored

awk: can't open file -e
 source line number 1
```

With a fancy shell such as ZSH you could do something horrible like the following but at that point you probably instead should put the script into a proper file and run that.

```
% print -l abc | awk -f <(print "{print}") -f <(print "{print}")
abc
abc
```

Comment: Process substitution (`<()`) doesn't require zsh; it works perfectly fine in bash or ksh86 or anything else with the usual widespread modern extension set. You might be thinking about `=()` as a zshism.

Comment: hey sorry, this doesn’t work when you have multiple `gawk —F` cmds

Answer (score 3):

> With sed -e you can call sed multiple times without using multiple pipes.

Using `-e` is not equivalent to pipes; it's equivalent to the semicolon (more accurately the newline).

You can compare with this example:

```bash
$ echo foo | sed -e 's/foo/foo\nfoo/' -e 's/^foo$/bar/'
foo
foo
$ echo foo | sed 's/foo/foo\nfoo/;s/^foo$/bar/'    
foo
foo
$ echo foo | sed 's/foo/foo\nfoo/' | sed 's/^foo$/bar/'   
bar
bar
```

Same deal with awk/gawk. You can use gawk's `-e`, but you can also basically just concatenate the code. Both are essentially the same but different than piping:

```bash
$ echo foo | gawk -e '{sub(/foo/, "foo\nfoo")}' -e '{sub(/^foo$/, "bar")}' -e '1'
foo
foo
$ echo foo | gawk '{sub(/foo/, "foo\nfoo")} {sub(/^foo$/, "bar")} 1'   
foo
foo
$ echo foo | gawk '{sub(/foo/, "foo\nfoo")} 1' | gawk '{sub(/^foo$/, "bar")} 1' 
bar
bar
```

Comment: didn’t say it was equivalent to multiple pipes, actually I think it’s better than multiple pipes, but why is everyone focusing on `sed -e` I’d like the behaviour that `sed -e` allows but with multiple `awk -F` cmds, that’s what the question was about, seems everyone is seeing a different question, can you help?

Comment: or now that I know about `;` delimitation with multiple `sed` cmds, how can I use this with multiple `awk -F` cmds (works fine with multiple `awk` cmds)